# How to parse the XML element id value

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I want to be able to parse the id value for this XML. Not all Apps have a note, so I would like to only parse it when the value is not NULL.

I know I'm very close, but I'm not getting anywhere. All I can print is the Note and the part into the page.

```
   <App action="A" id="1">
      <BaseVehicle id="5912"/>   <!-- 1991; Acura; Legend -->
      <EngineBase id="561"/>   <!-- V6; 3.2L; ; 3206cc -->
      <FuelDeliveryType id="5"/>   <!-- FI -->
      <Note>Dust and odor filter, Replaces F4476 once inventory is depleted.</Note>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <PartType id="6832"/>  <!-- Cabin Air Filter -->
      <Position id="1"/>  <!-- N/A -->
      <Part>F4476C</Part>
 </App>
```

Here's my function:

```
   function xmlParser(xml) {
    $('#load').fadeOut();
    $(xml).find("App").each(function(){
      $("#container").append('<div class="app"><div class="baseVehicle">Make Model:' + $(this).find("id").text(0) + ' <div class="engineBase">Engine:' + $(this).find("EngineBase").text() + '<br/>Note:' + $(this).find("Note").text() + '<br/>Part:' + $(this).find("Part").text() + '</div><br/></div>');
        $(".App").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

[HTML parsing sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ3H8.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you use the verb "to parse?". Parsing something means identifying its internal structure and breaking it up into parts. If the id value were "ABC-xyz/3" I can see how you might do that. But your example id is "1" - how do you parse "1"?

Comment: Michael, I'm a noob developer sorry for the misuse of language. I think I meant to say print out, not parse. As you can see in the picture the note prints, but not the rest of the content. Hope that makes more sense.